# Problems with Else If statements in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on this program that uses a few lines of code that worked that last time I used them but the only difference this time is that I need to use else if's instead of a basic if else statement. Still trying to learn how to really use this but any help would be appreciated. My error is stemming from the if statement and I have a feeling it is to do with the float result; line.

```
    private float caravan = 35;
private float wigwag = 25;
private float tent = 15;

private float caravan(float value){
    return value * caravan;
}
private float wigwag(float value){
    return value * wigwag;
}
private float tent(float value){
    return value * tent;
}

Button bookButton;
public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText bookAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNights);
    EditText bookFinal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBooked);
    float bookResult = Float.parseFloat(bookAmount.getText().toString());
    float result;

    RadioButton cbSelected = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radCaravan);

    if(cbSelected.isChecked()){
        result = caravan(bookResult);
    } else if (result == wigwag(bookResult)){

    } else if (result == tent(bookResult)){

    }
    bookFinal.setText(String.valueOf(result));

}
```

Comment: You should study some Java **fundamentals**.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you put a semicolon at the end of your statements, and you don't use the == operator:

```
if(cbSelected.isChecked()){
        result = caravan(bookResult);
    } else if (result = wigwag(bookResult);{

    } else if (result = tent(bookResult);{

    }
```

Fix by removing the semicolons and using the equality operator:

```
if(cbSelected.isChecked()){
        result = caravan(bookResult);
    } else if (result == wigwag(bookResult){

    } else if (result == tent(bookResult){

    }
```

Comment: I think I've just been starting at this for too long. I made these edits earlier and it didn't seem to do much but now it's working for the most part. The only issue now is that the calculation only seems to work with caravan and not with the other two, returning 0 following any input.

Answer (score 1):

used `==`  instead of `=` operator

```
if (result == wigwag(bookResult))
```